# Python3 - Change the type of specific list elements

Tags: list, sorting, python-3.x

I have a list:

> alist =
>   [('A','1','2','DEF'),('B','100,'11','XYZ'),('C','6','9','ABC')]

and I want to sort the list on 2nd and 3rd element, but before I do so I want to convert the  type of these elements from string to integer. How can I do so in most pythonic way?

I know I can read the list, convert elements to integer, add all elements to a new list and finally sort:

```
newList = []
for i in alist:
   a,b,c,d, = i
   newList.append((a,int(b),int(c),d))

newList.sort(key=itemgetter(1,2))
```

but what if each tuple in my list has 100 elements (above list had just 4) and I just want to convert a few them (like in above list - b and c) to integer type?

Bade

Comment: The equivalent of C#'s `Select` is `map` right? Or something along those lines. Why not use that to build a generator over your initial list and let Python take care of conversions when (if) you need em.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to convert them if you only want to sort on them:

```
alist.sort(key=lambda x: (int(x[1]), int(x[2])))
```

...

```
newList = sorted(alist, key=lambda x: (int(x[1]), int(x[2])))
```

Comment: Getting an error: parsed.sort(key=lambda k:(int(-k[9]),int(k[14]))) 
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str

Comment: Convert first, *then* negate. `-int(...)`

Answer (score 0):

If I inderstand the question, you really want to sort tuples by key, which needs to be converted to integer.

I would do

```
sorted_list = sorted(alist, key=lambda tup: int(tup[1]))
```

Comment: Ignacio's answer i guess is more correct as it sorts not only by second element but 2nd and 3rd as requested.